# Would it be possible to propel a spaceship by pushing against the sun's magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, rocket-science, space, propulsion

Would it be possible to power a space ship by generating a magnetic field opposed to the sun's? For example, the spaceship could generate a magnetic field using massive coils of superconducting wire. If the coils were shielded from the sun's light, then the space ship wouldn't need to expend any energy keeping them cold. The space ship could keep itself stable using regular thrusters to keep it from rotating towards the sun.

Could this method of propulsion generate more thrust than an ion drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sun's magnetic field is extremely weak: the average field on the surface of the sun is only about $1~\rm gauss$, only twice that of the earth's. The field strength of a dipole falls off as $1\over r^3$, which comes out to about $10^{-7}~\rm gauss$ at $1~\rm AU$. It would take a massive magnet to give even a $1~\rm N$ force, and that force would get even smaller as you get farther from the sun.

Answer (score 1):

We don't tend to use magnetic propulsion using the earth's magnetic field (except for a few satellites in low-earth orbit).  Mostly this is because the field strength is too low.

At the surface of the earth, you have a strength from the earth of about 500 milligauss.  The strength of the solar magnetic field near the earth is about 50 microgauss, or 4 orders of magnitude weaker.

This makes it nearly infeasible to use for propulsion.